# "electronics on the vehicle" VS "electronics in the vehicle"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. The requirements for electronics **on** the new energy vehicles are higher than that on traditional vehicles.
> 2. The requirements for electronics **in** the new energy vehicles are higher than that in traditional vehicles.

If I want to express that electronics **on/in** the new energy vehicles are more demanding in performance requirements, which one should I opt for?

Comment: It's not really a clear-cut choice. Probably ***in*** is more likely than ***on*** for your exact context. But ***for, of,*** or ***with*** (and probably other prepositions) would also be "valid".

Comment: Note that there are two different implications here, which aren't clarified by anything in your question text - (1) *the electronics are more demanding* (they need more electrical power, for example), and (2) *designers and/or drivers demand more (performance) from the electronics* (to manage / lie about exhaust emissions, for example! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, another question: the wording of the entire sentence [The requirements for electronics on the new energy vehicles are higher than that on traditional vehicles.]is okay, right?

Comment: I'd say the same ambiguity is still present in your rephrasing in that comment.